# Dropbox Python SDK SSL error

Tags: python, ssl, dropbox-api

I am learning how to use the Dropbox Python SDK. However, I run into a problem when I try to generate my request token. Here is the code I am using (note that I have replaced my actual app key and secret with APP_KEY and APP_SECRET here, but I used my actual app key and secret when I try it out.)

```
from dropbox import client, rest, session
APP_KEY = 'APP_KEY'
APP_SECRET = 'APP_SECRET'
ACCESS_TYPE = 'app_folder'
print 'Creating session object'
sess = session.DropboxSession(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, ACCESS_TYPE)
print 'Session created!\nCreating request token'
request_token = sess.obtain_request_token()
print 'Created request token!'
url = sess.build_authorize_url(request_token)
print url
raw_input()
access_token = sess.obtain_access_token(request_token)
client1 = client.DropboxClient(sess)
print client1.account_info()
```

I had the program print out messages as it was creating the different objects so that I could see where the error occurred. This is the output:

```
aaron@Aarons-Ubuntu-Computer:~/Twisted$ python example.py
Creating session object
Session created!
Creating request token
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 8, in <module>
    request_token = sess.obtain_request_token()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dropbox-1.4-py2.7.egg/dropbox/session.py", line 160, in obtain_request_token
response = rest.RESTClient.POST(url, headers=headers, params=params, raw_response=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dropbox-1.4-py2.7.egg/dropbox/rest.py", line 140, in POST
  return cls.request("POST", url, post_params=params, headers=headers, raw_response=raw_response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dropbox-1.4-py2.7.egg/dropbox/rest.py", line 64, in request
  conn = ProperHTTPSConnection(host, 443)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dropbox-1.4-py2.7.egg/dropbox/rest.py", line 214, in __init__
  self.cert_reqs = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CERT_REQUIRED'
```

I had tried using this code before, and I didn't experience this problem. I have also removed the Dropbox SDK and reinstalled it, with no result. What is causing this problem, and how can I fix it?

**UPDATE**

After adding Kannan's code, the output looks like this:
    `Ready`
     `Generating session`
`Session Generated!`
`Generating request token`
`['Certificate', 'CertificateOptions', 'CertificateRequest', 'Client', 'ClientContextFactory', 'Connector', 'ContextFactory', 'DN', 'DefaultOpenSSLContextFactory', 'DistinguishedName', 'KeyPair', 'Port', 'PrivateCertificate', 'SSL', 'Server', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'implementedBy', 'implements', 'implementsOnly', 'interfaces', 'supported', 'tcp']`
Then I get the error. I have tried re-created my SSL certificates with no luck.

Comment: Did you also do `print ssl.__file___`?  From the `dir(ssl)` results, it looks like you're getting Twisted's `twisted.internet.ssl` instead of the standard `ssl`.  Maybe your import path is messed up?

Comment: You were right! ssl.__file__ prints out /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/ssl.pyc. I had forgotten that I imported *-**twisted.internet.ssl**, so that I could establish a secure connection between my client and server programs. I tried changing the import statement to **from twisted.internet import ssl a twisted_ssl** so that it wouldn't interfere with Dropbox, and updated the reference to **ssl** in **reactor.listenSSL**. I am still having the ssl.CERT_REQUIRED error, though.

Comment: The Dropbox SDK does `import ssl`, so I don't know why the `twisted.internet.ssl` is getting imported.  Check your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to make sure it isn't set to include more than it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is strange.  The Python 2.7 docs definitely mention [`ssl.CERT_REQUIRED`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/library/ssl.html#ssl.CERT_REQUIRED).

Try modifying the SDK and, right before the line that fails, add in

```
print dir(ssl)
print ssl.__file__
```

That might help you figure out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I'm getting the same error. I tried what you suggested, and it turns out that ssl module has no attribute '**file**', and only has ['**doc**', '**loader**', '**name**', '**package**'] when I print dir(ssl). Also worth noting is that when I try print str(ssl) in google app engine, I see:
module 'ssl' (built-in)
but when I run python from the command line, I see:
module 'ssl' from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.pyc'
and the ssl from the command line has a **file** attribute.

Not sure how ssl is getting hijacked... but I'm pretty sure it is.

EDIT: **loader** is google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver_import_hook.HardenedModulesHook object at 0x1142684d0

EDIT: found a related problem here: [SSLError on Google App Engine (local dev-server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7308202/sslerror-on-google-app-engine-local-dev-server)